# how to detect ctrl + scroll in js or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to detect ctrl + scroll in js or jQuery or any other tool.
I am trying to do some dynamic layout code and I need to detect the screen width in different resolutions and I achieved that by a timer using setTimeout() but I see that it is not a performance wise 
any other idea may help too.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried `@media` queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctrlKey = 17;
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = true;
}).keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey) ctrlDown = false;
});

$(document).bind('scroll', function(){
    if (ctrlDown){ alert('scrolling with holding ctrl!'); }
});
```

I am afraid this isn't possibble, as neither mousewheel nor scroll event gets called if ctrl is hold

Comment: @pimvdb `This method is a shortcut for .bind('scroll', handler)`

Comment: You might want to use `mousewheel`, which works on Chrome (as opposed to `scroll`), although both do not get fired with control.

Comment: @pimvdb: exactly. I feel this isn't possible